# Вывод тэга <style> с аргументом без значения

Tags: xml, xls

Нужно вывести `<style amp-boilerplate>` используя xsl. `<xsl:value-of select="string()">` и `<xsl:text>` результата не дали.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<style amp-boilerplate>` не является правильно сформированным (well formed) xml. Поэтому напрямую вывести его невозможно.

Можно попробовать как-то так:

```
&lt;style amp-boilerplate>
```